# Can someone please explain why is array2 get sorted if I only applied sorting on Array 1 and created array2 as a NEW array? This is javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let array1 = [88,66,33,44,11,67,32,56];
let array2  = new Array(array1);
array1.sort();
console.log(array2);
```

Created an array1 with random values. Created an array2 using new keyword and initialized it with array1. Sorted array1 and printed out array2. I expected array2 to be unsorted

Comment: You created an array called `array2` with one element in it: `array1`.  You see that your results are double-nested in `[ [ ... ] ]` right?  You might want to review the documentation for the [Array() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) and notice that it does not magically crack open and copy an array you pass to it.

Comment: If you want to make a copy of an array, use `let array2 = [...array1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `new Array` is called, a number of things can happen. [See here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-constructor).

- If no arguments are passed, then an empty array is created.
- If one argument is passed, and the argument is a number, a new array with a length of that number is created.
- If one argument is passed, and the argument is not a number, a new array is created, with a single value - that of the passed argument.
- If multiple arguments are passed, a new array is created, with a value for each argument.

So if you pass a single non-numeric argument, you create a new array with that one argument as a value. Passing an array as the argument results in the creation of an array which has one value, where that value is the passed array.

The value is *the passed array itself*, not a copy:

```js
const array1 = [88,66,33,44,11,67,32,56];
const array2  = new Array(array1);
console.log(array2[0] === array1);
```

So when you sort the array (using either reference of `array1` or `array2[0]`), because they reference the same array, you'll see the sorted result no matter which one you examine later.

> I expected array2 to be unsorted

Copy the array properly instead. Don't use `new Array`.

```
const array2 = [...array1];
```

Comment: This is it. I wanted to initialize array2 with array1, instead I set it as 0th element of array2. I didn't realize the output is [[...]]. Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters which you pass to the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) are the elements in the new array (unless it's a number).

When you pass `array1` to the constructor, it is not cloned. Rather, the array is set as the first item in a new array.

If you want to clone it, you can spread the array, which converts it to a list of parameters from which the `Array` constructor creates a new array.

```js
let array1 = [88,66,33,44,11,67,32,56];
let array2  = new Array(...array1);
array1.sort();
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array2  = new Array(array1);
```

does not make a copy of `array1`. It's equivalent to:

```
let array2 = [array1];
```

This creates an array whose first element is a reference to the same array as `array1`.

Any modifications then made to `array1` will also affect `array2[0]`, and vice versa.

To make a shallow copy of `array1`, use:

```
let array2 = [...array1];
```